# Regexp help: match "John" or "Mike" or "Henry" but not "Johnny"

Tags: php, regex

I would like to match `John` or `Mike` or `Henry` but not `Johnny`.

I'm currently using this code, but I'd like to know how to do it with a single regexp:

```
preg_match("/John|Mike|Henry/",$TEXT) && strpos($TEXT,'Johnny') === false
```

Thanks for your help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a negative lookahead to exclude Johnny:

```
preg_match("/^(?!.*Johnny)(?=.*(?:John|Mike|Henry)).*$/", $TEXT)
```

### Demo

Comment: Hi Tim, and thanks a lot for your quick answer ! :-) I didn't need word-boundaries actually, so your former answer before you edited your post was the good one :
preg_match("/^(?!.*Johnny)(?=.*John|Mike|Henry)$/",$TEXT)

Comment: @fandetv I could have written it using only a single negative lookahead for Johnny, but decided to use lookaheads for both because it seemed cleaner to me.

Comment: Tim, I'm coming back to you because your regexp doesn't match "My name is Henry". Could you fix it please ?

Comment: @fandetv Fixed.  Forgot to wrap the alternation of names.  Sorry.

Comment: PERFECT ! Thanks for your quick fix Tim !